# Cannot import bokeh built in themes from bokeh.themes

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I am trying to set the theme for bokeh plots on jupyter lab.

To do so I am following the official docs, copying the exact code from https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/themes.html.

However, I get an error `cannot import name 'built_in_themes'`.

I assume the default themes location changed, but can't seem to find anything else besides the said page documenting bokeh.themes.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the default themes location changed

No, it has only ever been in the same location since it was added in version 1.0. The explanation is almost certainly that the version you are using is older than that.

Answer (score 0):

As bigreddot said, same location.

Check your Bokeh version:

```
$ python3.7
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
>>> import bokeh
>>> print(bokeh.__version__)
```

Or via jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
```

Following the example [here provided](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/themes.html), the output should look [like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usUAj.png)

Maybe you are just working in an environment with an older version.